# Route stays the same with links platform/:id in Navbar dropdown item React react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-nav

I want to achieve the link= /platform/:id each time the navbar dropdown item is selected. instead i get /platform/:id/platform:id

code for the Header.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'
import SearchBox from './SearchBox'
import { logout } from '../actions/userActions'

const Header = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo } = userLogin

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    dispatch(logout())
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <Navbar bg='dark' variant='dark' expand='lg' collapseOnSelect>
        <Container>
          <LinkContainer to='/'>
            <Navbar.Brand>ProShop</Navbar.Brand>
          </LinkContainer>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' />
          <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
            <Route render={({ history }) => <SearchBox history={history} />} />
            <Nav className='ml-auto'>
              <NavDropdown title='Nintendo' id='nintendomenu' to='/category/nintendo'>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendo3ds'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo 3ds</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendo2ds'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo 2ds</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendods'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo 2ds</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendoswii'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo Wii</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendowiiu'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo Wii U</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendoswitch'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo Switch</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendoswitchlite'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo Switch Lite</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/gameboy'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo Gameboy</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/supernintendo'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo Super</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendo64'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo 64</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/nintendods'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Nintendo DS</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
              </NavDropdown>

              <NavDropdown title='playstation' id='playstation'>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/playstation1'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Playstation</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/playstation2'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Playstation 2</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/playstation3'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Playstation 3</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/playstation4'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Playstaion 4</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/playstation5'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Playstation 5</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
              </NavDropdown>

              <NavDropdown title='xbox' id='' to=''>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/xbox1'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Xbox</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer>
                  <NavDropdown.Item to='platform/xbox360'>Xbox 360</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer>
                  <NavDropdown.Item   to='platform/xboxone'>Xbox One</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/xboxseriesx'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Xbox Series X</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
                <LinkContainer to='platform/xboxseriess'>
                  <NavDropdown.Item>Xbox Series S</NavDropdown.Item>
                </LinkContainer>
              </NavDropdown>


              <LinkContainer to='/cart'>
                <Nav.Link>
                  <i className='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i> Cart
                </Nav.Link>
              </LinkContainer>
              {userInfo ? (
                <NavDropdown title={userInfo.name} id='username'>
                  <LinkContainer to='/profile'>
                    <NavDropdown.Item>Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                  </LinkContainer>
                  <NavDropdown.Item onClick={logoutHandler}>
                    Logout
                  </NavDropdown.Item>
                </NavDropdown>
              ) : (
                <LinkContainer to='/login'>
                  <Nav.Link>
                    <i className='fas fa-user'></i> Sign In
                  </Nav.Link>
                </LinkContainer>
              )}
              {userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin && (
                <NavDropdown title='Admin' id='adminmenu'>
                  <LinkContainer to='/admin/userlist'>
                    <NavDropdown.Item>Users</NavDropdown.Item>
                  </LinkContainer>
                  <LinkContainer to='/admin/productlist'>
                    <NavDropdown.Item>Products</NavDropdown.Item>
                  </LinkContainer>
                  <LinkContainer to='/admin/orderlist'>
                    <NavDropdown.Item>Orders</NavDropdown.Item>
                  </LinkContainer>
                </NavDropdown>
              )}
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Route for /platform/:id in App.js:

```
<Route path="/platform/:id" component={HomeScreen} />
```

What i want to achieve:
http://localhost:3000/platform/xboxone  , when the xboxone is selected
http://localhost:3000/platform/xbox360,   when xbox360 is selected right after the xboxone

What i get currently:
http://localhost:3000/platform/xboxone , when the xboxone is selected
http://localhost:3000/platform/platform/xbox360, when xbox360 is selected right after the xboxone

Please help thank you!

Edit:
So, as i said whenever i select the Nav.Dropdown.Item, i get the result
for example: if i select Nav.Dropdown.Item playstation3, it goes to http://localhost:3000/platform/playstation3,
which i what i need.

NOw, after http://localhost:3000/platform/playstation2, if i select another Nav.Dropdown.Item playstation2, it goes to  http://localhost:3000/platform/playstation3/platform/playstation2

instead i want to go to http://localhost:3000/platform/playstation2, whenever another nav dropdown item is selected.

HomeScreen.js :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Paginate from '../components/Paginate'
import ProductCarousel from '../components/ProductCarousel'
import Meta from '../components/Meta'
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions'

const HomeScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const keyword = match.params.keyword
  const [sortOrder, setSortOrder] = useState('');
  //const category = match.params.id ? match.params.id : '';
  const platform = match.params.id ? match.params.id : ''; 
  const pageNumber = match.params.pageNumber || 1

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList)
  const { loading, error, products, page, pages } = productList

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts(platform, keyword, pageNumber, sortOrder))
  }, [dispatch, keyword, pageNumber, sortOrder])
  

  const sortHandler = (e) => {
    setSortOrder(e.target.value);
    dispatch(listProducts(platform, keyword, sortOrder));
  };


  return (
    <>
      <Meta />
      {!keyword ? (
        <ProductCarousel />
      ) : (
        <Link to='/' className='btn btn-light'>
          Go Back
        </Link>
      )}
      {/*category && <h2>{category}</h2>*/}
      <ul className="filter">
        <li>
          Sort By{' '}
          <select name="sortOrder" onChange={sortHandler}>
            <option value="">Newest</option>
            <option value="lowest">Lowest</option>
            <option value="highest">Highest</option>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader></Loader>
      ) : error ? (
        <Message>{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Row>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product._id} xs={6} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product product={product} />
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
          {/*<Paginate
            pages={pages}
            page={page}
            keyword={keyword ? keyword : ''}
          />*/}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: Can you give a link to codesandbox or someplace where the issue can be reproduced ?

Comment: Hey I urgently need to fix the issue but sandbox in above scenario will take lots of time? if you didn't understand the issue, I can edit the post.

Comment: Yep please do edit, share your relevant code files as well to debug.

Comment: i have edited the question.  I think  homescreen is the only relevant one to the question.

Comment: Do you wanna try using "exact" attribute on your LinkContainer?

Comment: thanks. I will try

Comment: Yep let me know if that worked...it is just that I am not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I tried with putting exact, its the same. But if i put to='/platform/playstation' instead of  to='platform/playstation' , the link changes to: http://localhost:3000/platform/playstation, http://localhost:3000/platform/playstation2  instead of  to: http://localhost:3000/platform/playstation/platform/playstation2

Comment: But the page doesn't refresh. So, we are stuck with the previous result.

Comment: where did you put exact in LinkContainer? Please let me know. i did <LinkContainer to='/platform/playstation1' exact>

Comment: Why do  you want to refresh the page, if your links are working fine ?

Comment: the link change, but content doesn't change. But if i manually refresh, the content changes. So, we need something that refreshes the page after each nav dropdown item is selected.

Comment: let me write an answer with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for your previous question, i guess it is figured out that we use

```
<LinkContainer to='/platform/nintendowiiu'> 

 // instead of
<LinkContainer to='platform/nintendowiiu'>
```

Now to address another issue that is your content should change you should make use of **useParams**. You can get URL parameters and set your state accordingly. This will cause your component to re-render and no need to refresh the page.

For using **useParams** you can just simply do the following

```
// First import
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

// Then use it in your component
const { platformId } = useParams();
```

The **platformId** is the name of variable that you might have used white you have set up your routes. So basically whatever you have set up as a variable after the colon.

```
<Route path="/platform/:platformId" component={HomeScreen} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a total noob. If its not a trouble can you add the code for the useParams too? Thanks!

Comment: Hey That is totally fine. That's how we learn. Though i have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Hey mate I don't understand. As you can see in above case. I have pass it as <Route path="/platform/:id" component={HomeScreen} /> , so where can i apply the useParams

Comment: You should apply useParams in the HomeScreen component and get "id" in that.

Comment: So, i import the useParms in HomeScreen. then const {platformId } = useParam() . Now, in app.js(where all the routes are) ,  <Route path="/platform/:platformId"> <HomeScreen /></Route> , is it right?

Comment: Do you wanna come over google meet or something ?

Comment: Sure. we can do that

Comment: Sure, or Skype works as well, live:shivamsharma1994 this is my username.

Comment: Thank you. google meet will be suitable for me. I am currently busy with something. let me know when you are free.

Comment: Text me over skype or mail2shivam94@gmail.com

Comment: Sure thank you. I have send you mail. If you are available i will send you meeting code